# Vuejs - access store outside of component

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I have this vuex store:

**store.js**

```js
export default createStore({
  state () {
    return {
      username: 'test',
      email: 'test@test.com',
    }
  },
})
```

I'm trying to protect all my routes but the auth ones (/signin and /signup) so I need access the vuex store from outside a component (in the `beforeEach` router method), searching on SO I found this should work:

**router.js**:

```js
import store from '@/store.js' 

const routes = {
  // routes defined here...
}

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes
})

router.beforeEach(function (to, _, next) {
  console.log('store', store);
  console.log('getters', store.getters);
  console.log('email', store.getters.email);

  if (!(to.path === '/signin' || to.path === '/signup')) {    
    store.getters.email ? next() : next('/signin')
  }
  next()
})
```

However the log for the getters returns undefined and consequently the log for email also returns undefined, the log for the entire store on the other side returns a bunch of properties, among them there is `_state` and in fact it does have the properties `email` and `username` set as I would expect.

**UPDATE**: here is a minimum reproducible example in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-grass-rttbon?file=/src/router.js:390-642):

So I'm really confused, what I'm missing here?

PD: I'm using Vue 3 and the options api

Comment: You can simply use their composable `import { useStore } from 'vuex'`: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api.html

Comment: And how could I achieve this using only the options api?

Comment: Where did you put your `router.beforeEach` function? In a Vue plugin?

Comment: @Kapcash no, I have a separate file where I create the router and define all my routes, I put the `beforeEach` there. I just updated the op

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown what's exported from store/index.js

Comment: There are two problems with your example: **1)** the app is initially trying to access a route which is not defined in `routes` (`/`); **2)** you're trying to access a getter which has not been defined on your store. Fixed both problems [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-leaf-1nq5mb?file=/src/router.js) and everything works fine.

Answer (score -1):

It seems the way to access the store outside a component is through the `state` property and not from `getters`

This is the working code for the beforeEach router method:

**router.js**

```js
import store from '@/store'

router.beforeEach(function (to, _, next) {
  const { path } = to;
  if (path !== "/signin") {
    store.state.email ? next() : next("/signin");
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```